# How can you store all of the files associated with a Rails view component in one place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

As much as I love Rails it has a tendency to scatter the components of a particular view far and wide across the file system. And this gets confusing.

### Rails' view of a web page

Rails has a view of a webpage that's driven by layouts, templates and partials. I think this stems from the old PHP way of looking at things where you view the page as a document and some parts of the document need to be re-rendered in other documents.

However a modern web-page is far less a document and far more a grid on which a series of components are laid out. Each component does different things and has its own styling, logic and layout. Components should also be easily usable elsewhere.

This is similar to the concept of a partial except that we're saying that that partial should also contain the details of its styling and logic, not just the HTML (I believe this is how React views the world).

### A component-driven view of a web page

For the sake of simplicity I'm going to say that an actual HTML view is made up of nested components where each component has:

- an HTML template
- a ruby view-helper file - ideally, isolated [ViewObjects](https://medium.com/m/global-identity)
- a CSS file
- a file with RSpec tests

### By default, rails scatters the parts of a single component all around the file system

At the moment, these are scattered far and wide across our Rails project which makes it really hard to track things at scale and be certain of what relates to what

- the view logic is in `/helpers` (or since we've started using [ViewObjects](https://medium.com/m/global-identity), `/view_objects/...`
- the html is stored in /views/...`
- the CSS is in `/assets/stylesheets/...`
- the tests are in `/spec/...`

With everything all over the place it makes it hard to ensure that the logic, tests, styling and templates are all well componentised and they have a tendency to start spilling over each other's responsibilities.

### Contrast this to our front end logic (Angular)

Our front end is entirely Angular. We've made it our own custom setup over the years but each Angular component has its own directory and in the directory is (let's say for a contact form):

- `contact_form/contact_form.js` - the directive (logic) for the component
- `contact_form/contact_form.html` - the HTML template for the component
- `contact_form/contact_form.css.scss` - the CSS for the component
  (ideally we would also have tests in here but we haven't got that far yet

### Is there a way to group the assets for a Rails component in the same directory?

I would like to do the same with the Rails components we use. I'd like to have a single directory for each component (let's say a contact form) that includes:

- `/contact_form/contact_form_view_object.rb` - the ViewObject that controls the logic
- `/contact_form/contact_form.html.haml` - the HTML template
- `/contact_form/contact_form.css.scss` - the CSS for the template
- `/contact_form/contact_form_spec.rb` - the RSPEC files for the component

This way the responsibilities of the component and the associated tests and styling are far more explicit and it becomes easier to grow the project without getting into a huge mess of intersecting responsibilities.

Is this possible though?

Comment: that might be a good entrypoint example : https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/evil-front-part-1/ then loading spec files would just be a matter of specifying the root folder I guess

Comment: @Ben - super interesting. A bit more than I need at this particular stage but really good

Comment: at first it looks a bit trendy, but there are many interesting stuff in there. The one thing i didn't know was about completely changing the view path — then, understood folders structure could be completely tweaked. rspec root folder ? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/configuration/setting-the-default-spec-path

Comment: haven't tried but heard of; https://github.com/komposable/komponent